# LiveData deactivates observer in Fragment after popping it up from backstack

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-lifecycle, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

There is a task I need to perform every time user comes to`HomeFragment`. It doesn't matter if it was newly created or user comes back to this `Fragment`.

It works fine when newly created, but when coming back from back stack the observer is not called. What I found using debugger is that `LiveData` has Observers, **but `hasActiveObservers()` returns false**. I tried to manipulate and observe/removeObserver from different lifecycle callbacks with no success. Couldn't find clear explanation in Google as well.

Here is my `HomeFragment.java`:

```
public class HomeFragment extends BaseFragment {
    //.......
    private ImportViewModel viewModel;

    private Observer<State> observer = state -> {
        //update UI depending on a state
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(ImportViewModel.class);
        observeViewModel();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        //execute here since onCreate() is not called when coming from backstack
        viewModel.importFile();

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        viewModel.liveDataState.removeObserver(observer);
    }

    private void observeViewModel() {
        viewModel.liveDataState.observe(this, observer);
    }

    //.......
}
```

And `ImportViewModel.java`

```
public class ImportViewModel extends ViewModel {

    //......
    public MutableLiveData<State> liveDataState = new MutableLiveData<>();
    //......
    public void importFile(){
        disposables.add(repository.importFile()
                .subscribeOn(subscribeOnScheduler)
                .observeOn(observeOnScheduler)
                .subscribe(this::onNext, this::onError, this::onComplete));
    }

     private void onNext(SomeResponse resp){
        liveDataState.setValue(new State(resp));
    }

    private void onError(Throwable t){
        liveDataState.setValue(new ErrorState(t.getMessage()));
    }

    private void onComplete(){
        liveDataState.setValue(new CompleteState());
    }
}
```

Why is Observer becomes inactive?

Comment: onCreateView should call when coming from backstack?

Comment: @PavelPoley, yes. It's called.

Comment: you are using FragmentManager().beginTransaction().add() or replace() above HomeFragment?

Comment: @PavelPoley, I do `replace`. I tested the lifecycle and it's for sure observer is not removed, since onDestroy wasn't called and it starts with onCreateView

Comment: so if you go back onCreate not called and onCreateView called?

Comment: @PavelPoley, exactly. That's correct behavior.

Comment: you tried to move the code from onCreate to onCreateView? or to use getActivity instead 'this'?

Comment: ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity , viewModelFactory)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181224/discussion-between-yurets-and-pavel-poley).

Comment: trying to reproduce the issue, without success, importFile() is called when come back to home fragment, if you could upload demo with this issue to github would be nice

Comment: @PavelPoley, importFile() is called for me too. I think it's related to LiveData's state. It's probably getting the same result and doesn't notify observer, since value is the same. But it's only an assumption, I didn't have time to test it yet.

Comment: Sorry, i mean onChange in observer is called when returning to to home fragment, even with same value, maybe you doing some manipulations in baseFragment

Comment: @PavelPoley, it turns out I can't reproduce this issue in new project. The original one is quite large to add everything step-by-step and see which point it fails on. I've overcome this issue by resigning from calling multiple onNext() for status update in the UI and just used Single. It might have something to do with livedata.setValue() calls, I dunno. I guess I'll not seek further, too specific issue and way too many circumstances could combine to produce this issue. Anyway, I appreciate your support. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem. What my case was I was going to another fragment from home fragment and I was maintaining state of fragment by setting fragment view to global and in on create view method I checked first if the view is not null then do not setup anything. Was working fine till that.

My problem was when I came back from that fragment the changes in live data was not observing.

I managed to do it in onResume method this way.

```
private fun setupObserver() {
        val observer: Observer<MutableList<Post>> = Observer {
            //            textView.text = homeViewModel.text.value?.get(0)?.name ?: "Loading"
            Log.d(
                AppConstants.GLOBAL_LOGTAG,
                "observed with current page = ${homeViewModel.getMetaData().currentPage}"
            )
            //logic to show progress

            if (!isObservedAtLeastOneTime) {
                showProgress()
            }
            if (homeViewModel.getMetaData().currentPage == 1) {
                list.clear()
                list.addAll(homeViewModel.mutableLiveData.value!!)
                recentPostsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            } else {
                list.clear()
                list.addAll(homeViewModel.mutableLiveData.value!!)
                recentPostsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
            if (isObservedAtLeastOneTime) {
                hideProgressAndShowContent()
            }
            isObservedAtLeastOneTime = true
            isLoading = false
            swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
        }
        if (!homeViewModel.mutableLiveData.hasActiveObservers()) {
            homeViewModel.mutableLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, observer)
        }
    }
```

And in on resume method.

```
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if(!homeViewModel.mutableLiveData.hasActiveObservers()){
            setupObserver()
        }
    }
```